# ¿Cómo editar DatePicker JSP?

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-datepicker

Tengo un formulario en jsp que solicita seleccionar una fecha que no sea mayor al dia de hoy, pero en mi datapicker no realiza tal funcion, estoy usando este código *javascrip* :

```
<script>
$(".datepicker").pickadate({ 
     selectMonths: true, 
     selectYears: 20, 
     max: 0 })
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El *datepicker* no tiene nada que ver con JSP; el JSP se ejecuta en el servidor y el JQuery (incluyendo *datepicker*) en el navegador.

Comment: Y en todo caso, la documentación de JQuery te da la respuesta en un minuto de reloj: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

Comment: Falto aclarar ese pedazo de código lo tengo en mi __plugin.js__